# comparing and picking up elements from two arrays (python)

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I have what I hope is a simple question, since I am new in Python-town :)

I am comparing two arrays "var1" and "var2", and via a loop I look up if the ith element of array "var1" is in "var2". If it IS, then I add this ith element of "var1" to "list1". The problem is that I also want to add the corresponding element of "var2" that matches into a second list "list2", but I do not have any second explicit index running over "var2" that I can recall for referring to it when adding it to "list2"

I've tried to figure it out with this artificial "j" and "np.where", but still the index "j" that I get refers to "var1", and not to "var2", so It doesn't help.... And obviously for "var2" I cannot use "i" since these two picked up elements do not necessarily need to be in the same position within their corresponding arrays....

Hope someone can help me!! Cheers everyone and thanks in advance!!  D.

```
for i in range (0, len(var1)) :
  if var1[i][0] in var2[: ][:,0]:
    j = np.where(var1[i][0] == var2[: ][:,0])
    list1.append(var1[i][0])
    list2.append(var2[j][0])
```

Comment: Can you show example input lists, and your expected output?

Comment: According to your explanation if the element of var1 is in var2, the same element should be added to both list1 and list2. So why do you need index of var2? Are you wanting to list1,list2 to be matching elements are the index of matching elements?

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you are using a second index when selecting an element from an array :

> var1[i][0]

Do you have a nested array ?